# For cookie containing access_token, setting secure = false, is that bad practice? Even if signed with jwt?

Tags: authentication, cookies

I'm using a server side rendering JS framework where the user signs into auth0, the client server then receives the access_token, uses jwt to sign it with our private key, and sends it to the client as a cookie.
The client server then checks for that cookie on every request. The secure flag must be set to false for the cookie to show up on the client side and be accessible with javascript. Is this still secure? It is being signed as a jwt on the server with a private key so I'm thinking that might be fine?
Ex.

```
[on the client server]
cookies.set(
                'token', 
                jwt.sign(data.access_token, [import private key] ),
                { sameSite: 'lax', httpOnly: true, path: '/', secure: false }
            )
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Setting `HttpOnly` is highly important as you already did but if you use SSL (which you definitely should) you should also use `secure: true` in production.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. To clarify, the code above - signing of the JWT and storing as a cookie - takes place after the user authenticates through auth0 (our auth provider). So after that takes place the cookie containing proof of auth is stored with the client and passed to the server on every request. So every request wouldn't be over HTTPS. Maybe I'm misinterpreting/misunderstanding your comment?

Answer (score 1):

### No, it is not safe!

The signature on a JWT prevents the *user* from forging or modifying the JWT data (which here is the value within the cookie) in order to *fool the server*. That's a very important property! But it has nothing to do with the cookie flags, which protect the cookie itself.

The **Secure** flag prevents the client (browser) from sending the cookie over insecure (HTTP, rather than HTTPS) connections. Without it, an attacker on the same local network as you, or in control of any network infrastructure between you and the server, might be able to *steal a user's entire cookie*. The attacker still wouldn't be able to modify the cookie, but they can present it to the web server along with their own requests, successfully *impersonating the user* (hijacking their login session). Thus, the Secure flag is essential to *protect the user*.

"But my whole site is HTTPS only, so it doesn't matter, right?" Sadly, that's not how it works. The browser will send cookies over any connection that it *thinks* is going to your site. When using HTTPS, the client can validate your TLS certificate to actually be sure it's going to you. When using HTTP, it can only use the domain name to guess who is on the other end. Any network attacker can *impersonate* your server by accepting a TCP request on port 80 whatever the attacker's actual IP is (remember, they control all the network traffic between you and the real server, and TCP - the protocol on which HTTP is build - has no inherent security), and the browser won't know the difference.

What if the victim never even tries to visit your site over plain HTTP, even when opening a new tab to your page? To get the browser to send an HTTP request to your server (within which it will include all non-Secure cookies), the attacker passively monitors your traffic until it sees you make a connection to *any* HTTP site. The attacker then modifies the response from that site to contain a plain-HTTP request to your site (might be an invisible request, like a stylesheet or script tag, invisible image, invisible iframe, etc.). The user's browser automatically makes the specified request. This attack does require the attacker to be a little "closer" (in network distance, not necessarily physical distance) to the victim - anywhere on the same LAN will still work, or controlling any router between the victim and their ISP - but that's still a real risk as people use shared networks all the time (at work, at hotels, at airports, at cafes, etc.).

"Okay, but what about HTTP Strict Transport Security?" That changes things! If you actually use HSTS across your domain and all subdomains, *and* your HSTS policy lasts long enough that your users will always have it active, *and* your users are on new enough browsers to support HSTS (this isn't hard, even IE11 has supported it for years, but some people use really old or niche browsers - possibly because they're on old mobile devices that don't get updates anymore - so you shouldn't always count on it), then HSTS does render the Secure flag redundant. Don't need to tell the browser "only send this cookie over secure connections" if you've already told it "only communicate with this domain over secure connections"! *However*, that's a lot of conditions that you might not be meeting, there's really no *cost* to using the Secure flag, and there's no way that anybody can browse the modern web at all using a browser so old it doesn't recognize the Secure flag.

So yeah, **lack of the Secure flag is a problem!**

---

Side note: why are you just storing the access_token? Are you actually using it to *access* anything (that is, to make a request to Auth0 or any other site that trusts Auth0), or are you simply using it as a source of a user identity field? Are you even ever validating that it's a real, legitimate access_token, or just assuming that since it either came from Auth0 directly or from a cookie that you are hopefully ensuring is signed by you, it's valid? If you aren't using the access_token *as an access token to some site other than your own*, you might as well just extract the user identity, along with any other data you have about the user (role/privileges, scope of this session, commonly-needed data like their name or whatever) and store that in the JWT directly.

---

As an addendum, it's *probably* OK, but using a JWT in this way is not necessarily a great practice. JWTs are good for two things:

1. Making it so that one server can create the cookie and a totally different one verify it
2. Making it so that the server doesn't have to store any session state itself

The first benefit is irrelevant here; you're setting a token that will only be consumed by the same server that created it, which does not require a JWT. The second benefit is plausibly valuable if you have a LOT of concurrent users, very long-lived sessions, or very limited server resources (RAM and/or database space)... but in practice, that's probably not true here. For example, it's commonly cited that using a JWT saves you from needing a database lookup on every authenticated request (the way you often do if using an opaque random token), but the thing is, you probably need to make a database request *anyhow* to actually service the request, so the difference doesn't mean much. Plus, if you have enough RAM, and the server either isn't clustered or the cluster shares a common cache, looking up the session doesn't necessarily take a *database* request at all because you can cache the random tokens and their associated session data. In fact, since the JWT doesn't contain any session data for the user, if you want to store any per-session data other than the access token, you'd need to either perform the DB request or cache lookup *anyhow*.

On the flip side, JWTs have some severe risks!

- **They can't be revoked**; they are valid until they expire. *When do yours expire?* You don't seem to be setting a lifetime, so it's probably whatever the library's default timeout is, which might be much longer than is safe. With a random token, you can remove the token from the server (cache or DB), and that's it, the session is dead. With JWTs, because you aren't storing the token on the server anyhow, the server can't remember whether a session is supposed to be ended (e.g. because the user logged out). Best practice when using a JWT is to make its lifetime very short - a single-digit number of minutes, often - and have a separate long-lived *refresh token* that can be used to re-generate the JWT with a new expiry. Of course, the refresh token can't be JWT itself; it needs to be... exactly the same kind of random opaque session token that you could have used in the first place. (Of course, with the JWT+refresh token pattern, you only have to look up the refresh token when actually refreshing the JWT, not on every request, so it probably does save you some server load.)
- Creating a JWT requires storing a secret - the signing key - and that's a big **single point of failure**. If an attacker ever steals or figures out the key, they can *forge any JWT they want, impersonate any user with any privileges* that your app recognizes. Even if the JWT is blatantly absurd - e.g. a lifetime of 2000 years - if the signature is valid, the server will think the JWT is legitimate. With a securely-generated random token, that's just not a risk at all, because the server remembers what tokens it generates, and the actual token is just a unique handle that the server maps to a session.
- Validating JWTs can itself be **expensive**! What type of key is your signing key (e.g. HMAC? Ed25519? ECDSA? RSA?) and how long is it? Some types of digital signatures are super fast (HMACs mostly), or at least not bad (Ed25519 or ECDSA with a reasonable key length). However, a lot of people using JWTs use RSA, which needs very large keys in order to be secure, and it's computationally expensive to use those long keys. Depending on exactly how the JWT validation is performed, this could be a *denial-of-service risk* to the server. That risk can be mitigated by using an implementation that runs at native speed (rather than in pure JS) and an algorithm that doesn't require long keys (since you are issuing and validating on the same server, you should be using HMAC anyhow, which is very fast and is secure with short keys; 128 bits is fine).
- JWT validation is vulnerable to **misconfiguration risks**. For example, if your server isn't specifically told what JWT signature type to expect, it might believe a JWT that claims it was issued with *no signature at all*! This type of JWT shouldn't ever be used in production... but neither should cookies without the Secure flag, so who knows what the library is doing? If the server trusts JWTs that claim to have been created with no signature, then of course the JWT's protections against forgery or tampering don't apply, and an attacker can present themselves as anybody they want.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for all the information and food for thought. I'm not sure I can address each question here, but I do appreciate you asking them to make sure we're not screwing anything up and for the education of myself and anyone else that might be viewing this. Ultimately this question came from our devops dept and it ended up landing on them to fix it. Our code automatically sets secure to true in prod and we learned they weren't serving over HTTPS like they should have been. We do verify the JWT on each request and I see what you're saying about extracting the user data.